# Error when deploying an activiti process

Tags: activiti

I created a simple activiti process with one rule.
Then i generated the .bar to deploy it on apache server. but whenever i try to deploy it i get the following error on apache's log: 
activiti java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.runtime.rule.AgendaFilter

I'm new at creating processes with activiti. can anyone help me?

I solved this first problem thanks to Abbas Kararawala

Now i have another problem:
my service class is implementing JavaDelegate interface and i'm calling it from a service task. i tested my process in embedded deployement and it worked. now i need it to work on standalone deployement but i keep getting the same error: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method componentEvent in org.activiti.explorer.ui.task.TaskDetailPanel$4 failed.

As Abbas Kararawala told me i should put my class in activiti-context.xml file, but i don't have one...
I do have i file named activiti.cfg.xml, i've placed it under src/main/resources, is that correct? (thus it's not working)

Comment: there's a .jar which you need to deploy along with the .bar file.

Comment: is it the jar generate on the deployement folder? i did put it under the lib folder of apache

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am calling a java class as a service in my process

Answer (score 1):

You should put your .jar files in  `/tomcat/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib`. **IMPORTANT:** It is required to put any external jar (used by your code) in the same folder.

see if this can help you - [activiti docs](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnJavaServiceTask)
This is for activiti 6.0

Comment: I did put the generated jar (create deployment artifacts) under /tomcat/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib. By external jars do you mean the jars that i'm calling in my pom.xml (since i'm working wiith maven)?

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I added all jars to the folder, i've got my process deployed successfully and i strated it. the first step in my process is a user task (entring data in a form), i was able to retrieve the task but when i click on terminate i've got the following errors:                                        1-com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method componentEvent in org.activiti.explorer.ui.task.TaskDetailPanel$4 failed                                       2- org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: deployment 1830 doesn't contain any rules

Comment: you're welcome - Hit the link and solved button if it helped you :) - FYI maybe you did not declared your java class as a bean or service.

Comment: actually my problem isn't solved yet. my service class is implementing JavaDelegate interface and i'm calling it from a service task. i tested my process in embedded deployement and it worked. now i need it to work on standalone deployement but i keep getting the same error:com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method componentEvent in org.activiti.explorer.ui.task.TaskDetailPanel$4 failed.  Thank you for your help